# 'GoogleUtilities/AppDelegateSwizzler/Private/GULApplication.h' file not found Error when adding rnfirebase in react native

Tags: firebase, react-native, cocoapods, react-native-firebase

I want to use cloud messaging of **firebase** in my react native project. I followed installation in
[docs](https://rnfirebase.io/#generating-ios-credentials) but I got error when running project using `react-native run-ios`:

> fatal error:
> 'GoogleUtilities/AppDelegateSwizzler/Private/GULApplication.h' file
> not found
> #import 'GoogleUtilities/AppDelegateSwizzler/Private/GULApplication.h'

I've run `pod install --repo-update`.

It works on *android* but on *ios* not.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [GoogleUtilities/AppDelegateSwizzler/Private/GULApplication.h' file > not found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62905585/googleutilities-appdelegateswizzler-private-gulapplication-h-file-not-found)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It has been solved in latest update.

Answer (score 0):

got the this error today.
add Podfile to

```
pod 'GoogleUtilities'
```

and change import to

```
#import 'GoogleUtilities/GULApplication.h
```