# Is there any work around for GoogleUtilities/AppDelegateSwizzler/Private/GULApplication.h' file not found

Tags: firebase, flutter, bitrise

I got this error message on Bitrise today, though until yesterday all CI/CD worked well.

> GoogleUtilities/AppDelegateSwizzler/Private/GULApplication.h' file not found

In local iOS environment, I could build my apps.
Any work around?
Thanks

Comment: Does this answer your question? [GoogleUtilities/AppDelegateSwizzler/Private/GULApplication.h' file > not found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62905585/googleutilities-appdelegateswizzler-private-gulapplication-h-file-not-found)

Comment: No, it's about ReactNative, this is for Flutter.

Answer (score 0):

I found some articles trying to fix this issue.
After I put this code on Podfile, everything started to work fine.

```
pod 'GoogleUtilities', '6.6.0'
```

Referenece
[GoogleUtilities/AppDelegateSwizzler/Private/GULApplication.h' file > not found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62905585/googleutilities-appdelegateswizzler-private-gulapplication-h-file-not-found)